# iOS App crashed when continuous zoom in zoom out in google map

Tags: ios, google-maps

I am in trouble. I have used Google map in iOS application. When I continue doing zoom in - zoom out in map till 1 to 1.5 minutes, it uses more memory and then it crash. I have attached crash screen shot. Please help me.

[image: When app crashed, I got error like this]

Comment: is not a crash , it is the exception enbale the zombies and check once

Comment: I am testing into iPhone6, Xcode version 7.3,iOS version 10.11

Comment: I enabled the zombies but can't get class name.

Comment: Google Maps SDK for iOS version: 1.9.14591.0

Answer (score 1):

Just Clear and remove the google map view in the following viewWillDisappear method.

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated] ;
    [m_mapView clear];
    [m_mapView removeFromSuperview] ;
    m_mapView = nil ;
}
```